# Django, how to reuse variable results get in a views in another one?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I have the following question for you. I want to know the best and elegant way to reuse some variable results obtained in a view in another one.

I'm trying to explain me better with an example.

I'have 2 differente app, app `A` and app `B`.

In app `A` views.py I have a lot of code to process data from the models with a creation of a lot of new variables. 
Now, in app `B` I have the necessity to reuse some variables obtained in views.py app `A`, but I wonna write again the same code to get them.

Is there a way to achive my goal?

> **EDIT**

Following the @sandeshdaundkar's suggestions I could overcome my problem creating a new function and call it in my views.py of each app.

I'm trying to achive this result but I'm not good at python's function and how call it inside my views.py.

I have created the following function in my_app/utility.py:

```
def my_func():

    defaults = list(0 for m in range(13))
    iva_debito = dict()
    for year, month, totale in(Ricavi.objects.values_list( 'data_contabile__year', 'data_contabile__month').
        annotate(totale=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('quantita') * F('ricavo')*(F('iva'))),
        output_field=FloatField())).values_list('data_contabile__year', 'data_contabile__month', 'totale')):
        if id not in iva_debito.keys():
            iva_debito[id]=list(defaults)
        index=month
        iva_debito[id][index]=totale

    iva_debito_totale={'IVA a Debito Totale': [sum(t) for t in zip(*iva_debito.values())],}

    context= {
        'iva_debito_totale':iva_debito_totale,
    }

    return context
```

And here my my_app/views.py: 
...
from .utility import my_func

```
def iva(request):
    data = my_func()
    iva_debito_totale=data['iva_debito_totale']

    context= {
        'iva_debito_totale': iva_debito_totale,
    }

    return render(request, 'iva/iva.html', context)
```

I have solved it with the solution above.

Comment: create a function that does the common calculation outside the view and call that function inside both the views

Comment: thanks, and the function in which folders?

Comment: you can create a `utils.py` file in the same Django app folder and import in views or write the function inside the `views.py` itself. Just make sure your function arguments are proper.

Comment: Ah okey thanks, I'm new in python, could you make a function example of my views (just with only one variable) and how can use it in my views?

Comment: okay let me check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func_name():
        # do calculation,
        return context_for_view_one, obj_to_reuse

def view_one(request):
    context, iva = func_name()
    return render(context=context) # context to be used in view a

def view_two(request):
    context, iva = func_name()
    return render(context=iva) # iva to be used in view b
```

```
def iva(request):
    data = func_name()
    iva_debito_totale = data['iva_debito_totale']
    return render(request, 'template.html', context={'totale': iva_debito_totale})
```

I hope this gives you an idea, we return 2 objects from common function. One which is to be used in view_one and others to be used in view_two. You can try something similiar

Comment: I want to thank you immensely, your answer has been very useful, but I'm trying to follow your suggestions but I have a difficult to get my aim. I have edit my question with your answer. Could you help me?

Comment: call that function inside the view and assign its return value to variable. Access the key by using `var_name['iva_debito_totale']`

Comment: does not work, django give me the following error `my_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' `. I have update my answer with your suggestions and with the error

Comment: please edit your question to only current views.py file. Single file as it is in your system,.

Comment: this should work, please debug using `pdb` library, also check exactly which line is breaking the code. The function and call seems correct to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213618/discussion-between-sandeshdaundkar-and-federico-de-marco).